# Send admin to a different login than users?

Tags: admin, hooks, login, wp-login-form

I have created a separate login page on `/login/` and have `wp-login.php` redirecting there as well - I have also hooked into a few WP login related hooks such as `wp_login_failed` so that people get redirected there.

However I have now decided I want admins to continue to be able to login from the standard place and keep this for users - no problem here as I can just direct users to `/login/` and remove the redirects.

Problem with doing that is on error users are going to get redirected to `/wp-login.php` again and if I put the redirects back then admin users will get directed to `/login/` instead.

How to handle this?

Comment: How do you think you can know whether someone is an admin before he logs in?

Comment: @flomei Well that's why you have a separate login for admins only. I guess a normal user *could* try and login from that page if they wanted - point is the user login page is for a separate member area and isn't really related to logging into the WP panel (it's about user experience for the admin).

Comment: Do you use the same login process (= the one build into WP) for users and admins?

Comment: @flomei I have made use of `wp_login_form` to create the additional login page.

Comment: Are the users saved in the same database, meaning `_users` table?

Comment: @flomei Yes. :)

Comment: In that case there is no difference, before the users are logged in. Just send the admins to the user login, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter.

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            //make wp-admin as your default place, if you customized it
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url('/login/');
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

### UPDATE

I am assuming that you are using `wp_login_form` for the custom login page and already hooked to `authenticate` to handle empty username and/or password issue.

We can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to check from where the request came from and redirect accodringly.

```
function wpse9845_my_awesome_login_fail( $username ) {
   $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
   // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default wp-login.php ot wp-admin screen
   if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
      wp_redirect( $referrer );
      exit;
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'wpse9845_my_awesome_login_fail' );
```

There's a bad side of the above code: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not supported by all user agent.

*Note([from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)): `HTTP_REFERER` - The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify `HTTP_REFERER` as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.*

Best way to do this is using a completely custom login page/form, along with authentication. [Here is a very good tutorial](https://pippinsplugins.com/creating-custom-front-end-registration-and-login-forms/).

Comment: Doesn't that just redirect them *after* a successful login and hence you already know if they're and admin or not; doesn't give them a separate place to login.

Comment: @Brett okay, looks like i misunderstood you. I thought, you wanted to redirect admin users to wp dashboard, and others to some other place.
Why would you want separate login forms, while you can easily do different action for different type of action, using only one login form?

Comment: Because it's about providing a good user experience. One section may be called "Member Login" styled like the site and the other could just be the normal wp login page.

Comment: @Brett How are you handling your custom login page? Did you use `wp_login_form`? Update your question with custom login form codes, authentication process and hooks you have done.

Comment: @Brett check my update.